# Deploy spring boot in heroku, error 503 code=H14

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, heroku-cli

I use https://start.spring.io/ to generate a springboot demo,I push this demo to heroku ,can  Build succeeded,But want I open app ,response error code 503

this demo [repository](https://github.com/hezhongfeng/demo)

show the log:

```
2022-06-24T08:24:11.653717+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=boiling-beach-29913.herokuapp.com request_id=db6e207c-93f4-4b77-81a0-85d5ef660535 fwd="156.249.9.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-06-24T08:24:12.095606+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-beach-29913.herokuapp.com request_id=83718790-a3c0-46dd-b17c-a05c04049a2e fwd="156.249.9.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

system.properties：

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

Procfile：

```
web: java -jar $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources->Free Dynos->open and save~